# Capitalization of first letter of string in c - Code a myprintf function in under 110 characters

Tags: c, capitalization

I need to make a `my_printf` function that takes a string, capitalizes only the first letter of the string (even if there are spaces before) and then does a \n, all in under 110 characters (spaces/tabs not included).

I can only modify the function in between the comments "TO BE DONE START" AND "TO BE DONE END".

This is the code I've written so far: the only problem I have with it is that in the output it doesn't capitalize the letter "l" of "looks OK :)" after the \t and I have no idea how to implement the capitalization of a character not in position q[0] of the string without going over the max limiter of 110 characters in this code; I know it requires a loop but I always seem to go over the limit.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_printf(char*p){
    char s[strlen(p)+1], *q=s;
    strcpy(s,p);

    /* TO BE DONE START */
    q[0]=toupper(q[0]);
    putchar(q[0]);
    for(*q=1;*q!='\0';++q) {
         putchar(*q);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    /* TO BE DONE END */
}

int main(){
    my_printf("hello world!");
    my_printf("How are you?");
    my_printf("i\'m OK, and you?");
    my_printf("1, 2, 3, testing ...");
    my_printf("\t  looks OK :-)");
    my_printf("bye bye!");
    return 0;
}
```

I need help in making this code as short as possible, here is the desired output:

```
 Hello world!
 How are you?
 I'm OK, and you?
 1, 2, 3, testing …
            Looks OK :-)
 Bye bye!
```

While mine is:

```
 Hello world!
 How are you?
 I'm OK, and you?
 1, 2, 3, testing …
            looks OK :-)
 Bye bye!
```

Comment: `while(isspace(*q))putchar(*q++); putchar(toupper(*q++);while(*q)putchar(*q++);` should work.

Comment: Do you have to deal with non-ascii characters?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: `char` arguments should be cast as `(unsigned char)` and an trailing newline is required.

Comment: @chqrlie as long as the input is really a string, there is no need for that. And otherwise, casting a spell wouldn't help much.

Comment: @JensGustedt: If the input is a string with 8-bit characters and `char` type is signed, both `isspace(*q)` and `toupper(*q)` would have undefined behavior. Casting the argument fixes this issue: `isspace((unsigned char)*q)` and `toupper((unsigned char)*q)`. See **7.4 Character handling <ctype.h>** *The header <ctype.h> declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char or shall equal the value of the macro EOF. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined*

Comment: @chqrlie, _"an int, the value of which shall be representable as an unsigned char"_ wouldn't casting an int to a char, signed or unsgined, just result in the original char? The high bits are just chopped of after having first been sign-extended to int.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie "casting an int to a char, signed or unsgined" is unclear.  The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55533187/capitalization-of-first-letter-of-string-in-c-code-a-myprintf-function-in-unde#comment97771835_55533187) was to cast the `char` to `unsigned char`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: no, casting a `char` as an `unsigned char` does not first extend the `char` to an `int`, it merely converts the possibly negative value to a value in the range `0..UCHAR_MAX` (with the same bit representation on 2's complement architectures), which will then be promoted to `int` when passed to `isspace` or `toupper`. It is very important not to pass negative values (except `EOF`) to these functions as they may use their argument as an index into a table of 257 entries. Most negative values would cause a reference outside the array or an incorrect index value.

Comment: @chqrlie, I see, but I feel very unhappy having to cast all those chars to unsigned and would expect the standard to provide a better interface. It can easily make the code unreadable. Why not do any casting inside those macros or functions?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: the cast cannot occur inside the macro because the functions must accept the value `EOF` **and** all `unsigned char` values. The C library has some shortcomings on platforms with signed `char` by default: `isspace()` is consistent with `getchar()`, but not with signed `char` values. The C libraries implement a partial workaround for this problem, accepting values between `CHAR_MIN and UCHAR_MAX`, but `EOF` (-1) cannot be distinguished from `'ÿ'` (also -1 for ISO8859-1). The simplest way to fix this potential problem is to tell the compiler to make `char` unsigned by default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `isspace` function - something like:

```
/* TO BE DONE START */
while (isspace(*q)) putchar(*q++);
for(*q = toupper(*q); *q; ) putchar(*q++);
putchar('\n');
/* TO BE DONE END */
```

Comment: The argument to `isspace` and `toupper` should be cast as `(unsigned char)` to avoid undefined behavior on negative `char` values.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `char` argument to `isspace()` and `tolower()` **must** be converted to `unsigned char` to avoid undefined behavior on negative `char` values on platforms with signed `char` type. Your code and all other solutions have this problem.

Here is a short one that does not modify the array (98 characters):

```
/* TO BE DONE START */
while (isspace((unsigned char)*q)) putchar(*q++);
if (*q) putchar(toupper((unsigned char)*q++));
puts(q);
/* TO BE DONE END */
```

An even shorter one modifying `s` (75 characters):

```
/* TO BE DONE START */
while (isspace((unsigned char)*q)) q++;
*q = toupper((unsigned char)*q));
puts(s);
/* TO BE DONE END */
```

Answer (score 1):

This makes me feel dirty:

```
/* TO BE DONE START */
int f = 1;
while (*q) {
  if (f && !isspace(*q))
    *q = toupper(*q), f=0;
  putchar(*q++);
}
putchar('\n');
/* TO BE DONE END */
```

84 non-whitespace characters.

Note the use of the comma operator to avoid having a `{}`, saving a character.

(Assumes that `char` is unsigned or if signed that the string it takes will never have a negative value in it.)

Comment: The argument to `isspace` and `toupper` should be cast as `(unsigned char)` to avoid undefined behavior on negative `char` values.

Comment: @chqrlie Hence my note at the bottom.

Comment: OK for the note, but this assumption deserves a comment. The use of `,` definitely looks bad... but you can save an extra byte with `if (f * !isspace(*q))`

Comment: @chqrlie It's code golf. Of *course* it looks bad. It'd look worse if OP hadn't said that whitespace didn't count towards the character limit.